# Can't create/write to file 'xxxx.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, macos

```
mysql> \T abc.txt
./mysql: Can't create/write to file 'abc.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
Error logging to file 'logPremiereQueries.txt'
```

I meet the same problem when I use Windows 8. I solve it by running cmd (MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client) as administrator. And then I could easily find the position of abc.txt. However, in Mac OS X, I do not know how to change the permission. And if log to file successfully, where to find this 'abc.txt'? Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Just leaving this here for the future...

If you are using Windows, open services. Right click on mysql service, select properties. In the properties window select Log On tab then Log on as: Local System account.

If you are ready, restart the service and you can select into outfile anywhere where you have permission to write.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide a specific path for a file when using `tee (\T)` command mysql will try to create or append to the file in the current working directory (directory from which mysql has been started)

The error is self explanatory - you just don't have permissions to write a file in a current working directory.

If you don't know (which is strange) what is your current working directory you can execute system [`pwd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pwd.1.html) command from mysql command prompt

```
mysql> \! pwd
```

Now to resolve the problem either:

1. change your working directory in terminal to the one that you have write permissions on (e.g. your home directory) and then start mysql client

   ```
   $ cd ~
   $ mysql -uusername -p dbname
   ```
2. in mysql prompt when using `tee (\T)` command specify a valid path to the directory that you have write permissions on e.g.

   ```
   mysql> \T /Users/username/abc.txt
   ```

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

please to see -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html

One fix is to start mysqld with the --tmpdir option or to add the option to the [mysqld] section of your option file. For example, to specify a directory of C:\temp

Comment: Thanks... your link was useful.  In particular, one of the comments at the bottom mentioned "give MySQL user FILE perms (CREATE USER MyDBconnecter...with FILE perms)", though instead of creating a new login, I did a `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'username'@'host'....`.  **Also** note that, in my case, I had to make sure to the target file in my `--tee=<path>\<file>.txt` was a _different_ file, from my processes' other logging:  before, I was using the same file for both, so one of the problems was that the tee *file was already open*.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem and solved this bug.

```
SELECT * FROM mahitab INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/mahitab.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINE;
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql-files/mahitab.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

We have to give the permission to

```
[root@localhost tmp]# chmod 1777 /var/lib/mysql-files/
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with windows 10 and, I also faced this problem when I used 'TEE'/'tee'/'\T' command. I solved it using these steps.
First, we have to create a text file in a notepad and save it. Then copy the file path and use it with the tee command. Don't forget to convert the backslashes to forward slashes.
Ex: TEE C:/Users/User-PC/Desktop/sqlfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to create a file and the quest to resolve the issue got me here. so I followed the recommendation by @jason to login as an admin and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34154313)