# mysqldump: Can't create/write to file 'dump.sql' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is my code;

```
mysqldump -h relational.fit.cvut.cz -P 3306 -u guest --password=relational --databases imdb_ijs --result-file dump.sql
```

And, I'm getting this error message;

```
mysqldump: Can't create/write to file 'dump.sql' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create/write to file 'xxxx.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446655/cant-create-write-to-file-xxxx-txt-errcode-13-permission-denied)

Comment: Check the permissions on the current directory where you run this command. You seem not to have permissions to create files in that directory.

Comment: The user you are running the command as does not have write access to the current directory. You need to: change directory permissions, run the command as a different user, or run it in a different directory actually owned by the current user